# Add, Delete, Update XML data in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, xml, forms

I have come up to a problem, that I'm not sure how to solve. I was able to do this with a database and php, but I can't seem to do it in Javascript(required), html and xml. I have the xml document  named `racelane.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RACELANE>
    <CAR>
         <CARNUMBER>1</CARNUMBER>
         <DRIVER>Erick Buque</DRIVER>
         <CARMAKE>Nissan</CARMAKE>
         <CARMODEL>350Z</CARMODEL>
         <YEAR>2011</YEAR>
    </CAR>
    <CAR>
        <CARNUMBER>2</CARNUMBER>
        <DRIVER>Sean Smith</DRIVER>
        <CARMAKE>Chevy</CARMAKE>
        <CARMODEL>Cobalt SS</CARMODEL>
        <YEAR>2010</YEAR>
    </CAR>
    <CAR>
        <CARNUMBER>3</CARNUMBER>
        <DRIVER>James Abbot</DRIVER>
        <CARMAKE>Honda</CARMAKE>
        <CARMODEL>Civic si</CARMODEL>
        <YEAR>2011</YEAR>
    </CAR>
    <CAR>
        <CARNUMBER>4</CARNUMBER>
        <DRIVER>Leigh Summers</DRIVER>
        <CARMAKE>Nissan</CARMAKE>
        <CARMODEL>Altima R</CARMODEL>
            <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
    </CAR>
    <CAR>
        <CARNUMBER>5</CARNUMBER>
        <DRIVER>Rick Littleton</DRIVER>
        <CARMAKE>Ford</CARMAKE>
        <CARMODEL>Mustang</CARMODEL>
        <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
    </CAR>
</RACELANE>
```

It gets ready by my html document `test7pub.html`. The javascript code reads the xml file and puts everything into a text box, I included an update and delete button, and another blank row with an add button, but I cannot seem to figure out how to the code for the three buttons with respect to xml (I've done it regularly). And then append/update the file. There is a bonus if I can sort, and warn or reject duplicate car numbers. Below is my html.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","racelane.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
document.write("<tr><th>CarNumber</th><th>Driver</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CAR");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<form action='test7pub.html' method='post'>");
  document.write("<tr>");         

  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='text' size='5' required name='carnumber' value=");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CARNUMBER")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(" </td>");

  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='text' name='driver' value=");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DRIVER")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(" </td>");

  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='text' name='make' value=");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CARMAKE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(" </td>");

  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='text' name='model' value=");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CARMODEL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(" </td>");

  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='text' name='year' value=");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(" </td>");

  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type=submit name=update value=update");
  document.write(" </td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type=submit name=delete value=delete");
  document.write(" </td>");

  document.write("</tr>");
  document.write("</form>");  
  }
document.write("<form action='test7pub.html' method='post'>");
document.write("<tr>");       

document.write("<td>");
document.write("<input type='text' size='5' required=true name='ucarnumber' >");
document.write(" </td>");

document.write("<td>");
document.write("<input type='text' required name='udriver' >");
document.write(" </td>");

document.write("<td>");
document.write("<input type='text' required name='ucarmake' >");
document.write(" </td>");

document.write("<td>");
document.write("<input type='text' required name='ucarmodel' >");
document.write(" </td>");

document.write("<td>");
document.write("<input type='text' required name='uyear' >");
document.write(" </td>");

document.write("<td>");
document.write("<input type=submit name=add value=add>");
document.write(" </td>");

document.write("</tr>");
document.write("</form>");   
document.write("</table>");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I got the inspiration and syntax from w3 schools, I just built on it to do what I needed. I am trying to avoid databases and use the XML instead. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you can't add delete/update btns for every record ?

Comment: correct. I'm not sure how to write the functions for that. I've written them for regular rows in the classic sense, but how would it be done for XML?

Comment: Why you don't use AJAX for delete and update ?

Comment: I dont know how to use that. I am new to web development. I've seen it, and I know it has javascript. I just don't know how I would write such a function.